# I need help. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have no idea how to fix this

Tags: dpkg, sudo, configure

So I've had trouble installing some drivers and updates and this is where the internet has led me, but I can't find a solution to these problems.

When I put in`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

This is the output:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on cups-common (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of cups-common on system is 2.1.3-4.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-bsd:
 cups-bsd depends on cups-common (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of cups-common on system is 2.1.3-4.

dpkg: error processing package cups-bsd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-client:
 cups-client depends on cups-common (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of cups-common on system is 2.1.3-4.

dpkg: error processing package cups-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package libcups2:amd64 (--configure):
 package libcups2:amd64 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1 cannot be configured because libcups2:i386 is at a different version (2.1.3-4)
dpkg: error processing package libcups2:i386 (--configure):
 package libcups2:i386 2.1.3-4 cannot be configured because libcups2:amd64 is at a different version (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-filters:
 cups-filters depends on libcups2 (>= 1.7.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-filters (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-browsed:
 cups-browsed depends on libcups2 (>= 2.0.2); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-browsed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsmime1:amd64:
 libcupsmime1:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsmime1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-daemon:
 cups-daemon depends on libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-daemon depends on libcupsmime1 (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package libcupsmime1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsppdc1:amd64:
 libcupsppdc1:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsppdc1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsimage2:amd64:
 libcupsimage2:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsimage2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-filters-core-drivers:
 cups-filters-core-drivers depends on libcups2 (>= 1.7.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-filters-core-drivers depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-filters-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupscgi1:amd64:
 libcupscgi1:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupscgi1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups
 cups-bsd
 cups-client
 libcups2:amd64
 libcups2:i386
 cups-filters
 cups-browsed
 libcupsmime1:amd64
 cups-daemon
 cups-core-drivers
 libcupsppdc1:amd64
 libcupsimage2:amd64
 cups-filters-core-drivers
 libcupscgi1:amd64
```

Comment: try this `sudo apt -f install && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: @George I tried them, but it gave me the same "errors were encountered while processing:" message

Comment: To get good help please you need to be explicit about what you were doing that got you here. As I see you only _said_ you ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` meaning that you had previously tried installing and your `dpkg tool` broke and you tried to reconfigure. So try and add more information.